# Why allocate space for this variable?

Tags: .net, azure, memory-management

I found this and I wonder why there is a memory allocation on the the variable in the loop (.... 0x20;). It looks like the variable is simply filled up with spaces. But why would one do this when we initialize the byte variable with the size ?

```
long fileByteLength = package.Properties.Length;
byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileByteLength];
for (int i = 0; i < fileByteLength; i++)
{
    fileContent[i] = 0x20;
}
// Download the file aa a byteArray to the fileContent variable
package.DownloadToByteArray(fileContent, 0);
```

Comment: What is `package`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: it's not really important what package is. The question is around memory allocation of a variable and why it would look like this.

Comment: If it's not important, then just delete the whole block of code and be happy.

Comment: This side effect of SOs moderators is kinda of a joke, simply because my rep is not there. You should ask yourself if you think that's a proper comment, honestly!

Comment: It works for me, if you think it's a joke, feel free to go to [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and discuss some improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer is: because the programmer wanted to have it filled up with spaces. Initializing it with the length means you get a lot of 0 bytes. Why did the programmer want spaces? I have no idea. The whole thing is bad cargo-cult programming (meaning somebody did it because he saw somebody else doing it, without understanding how it works or what it does).

You should either use a [stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtostream(v=azure.10).aspx) or use the [return value of that method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtobytearray(v=azure.10).aspx). If your quality guideline is "good programming", then that loop has to be deleted and replaced by either of the above solutions.

My preference would be the stream (could be a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx)) so that you get rid of all that byte-counting and buffer shifting and return-value-checking. That is what the stream abstraction was made for.

Comment: Thank you! Could it be a speed/optimization thing ?

Comment: I doubt that. It will be overwritten anyway. The only positive effect is that the array *is* filled with spaces in the end, even if *less* bytes are written. But again... just ignoring the return value and filling with spaces beforehand is the hackiest way to handle that. Like some 80's C programmer read only half the API and decided to "optimize" it. It's not optimized, it's simply wrong.

Comment: Especially since this is only "working" (I would not consider it working, but you know what I mean) if the data is text. Everything else (images, files, whatever data) is seriously broken if you add spaces in the end.